# Do invariants and co-invariants for a cyclic group have the same dimension?

Tags: representation-theory, positive-characteristic

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$ with an action of the cyclic group $C_p$  of order $p$. We can now form the two vector spaces of invariants $V^{C_p}$ and co-invariants $V_{C_p}$.

> **Qustion:** Do we always have $\dim{V^{C_p}=\dim V_{C_p}}?$

Just to say what I do know about this question:

1. This is true for the trivial representation and the regular representation and hence for any direct sum of them. Namely, for any permutation representation.
2. When working over a field of characteristic 0, the canonical norm map provides a natural isomorphism from the co-invariants to the invariants.
3. Over $\mathbb{F}_p$, the norm map is not an isomorphism and in fact, no natural isomorphism exists.
4. For arbitrary $p$-groups $G$ in place of $C_p$ this is false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, $V^{C_p}$ and $V_{C_p}$ are the kernel and cokernel of $V\xrightarrow{g-1}V$, $g$ a generator of $C_p$, so they have the same dimension.

Comment: That's right... I feel a bit stupid :)